# How to hide navigation link that are un visited?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `ul` based navigation bar like `a b c d e` (I am using `<a>` tag in `li` to navigate). I have 4 pages and above each represent one page, and I use them to allow user to navigate. It's a form, so I want to show navigation links till the current page and previous pages he visited, and remaining should be hidden from the user. For example, if user is on 2nd page then only `a` and `b` will show on navigation menu, and if he progresses to 3rd page by clicking next then `c` should be visible on navigation link with previous links. Answer should be in AngularJS / jQuery or in JavaScript

---

I am using navigation through controller , with sref tag

```
<li class="active lidesign " >
  <a ui-sref="page.passenger_detail" href="/#/page/passenger_detail"
     id='ac' class="customcolor" > Passenger Details 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play customglyphicon hidden-xs">
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am still in phase of figuring out , how it can be done. i have different scenario in my mind but no one seems to work or i am not there to grab the solution. if you can help me then please do.

Comment: Can we define some global variable which will have name of pages and we use hide and show mechanism based on values

Comment: I am not a fan of global variables but if there is a work around in global variable then tell me. i would love to know the solution.

Comment: with angularjs you would need a routing module, which is either `ngRoute` or `ui.router`. Are you using either one?

Comment: I am using navigation through controller , with sref tag. aleksey.